# Bamboo Jobs kick off from Rundeck and Execute Bamboo jobs from command Prompt

Tags: bamboo, rundeck

Have the following requirments.

1. Execute a Bamboo Job from RunDeck. ( I found plugins to execute Rundeck job from Bamboo, need to vice versa)
2. Call the jobs created in Bamboo by Command Prompt ( Thinking to execute the jobs using command prompt in Rundeck)

Please suggest any alternatives for the above task. Utilmate goal is to get the bamboo jobs kick off from Rundeck.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using the REST API provided by Atlassian. Documentation can be found [here](https://developer.atlassian.com/display/BAMBOODEV/Using+the+Bamboo+REST+APIs) and, more specific to your use case, [here](https://developer.atlassian.com/display/BAMBOODEV/Bamboo+REST+Resources#BambooRESTResources-BuildQueueService).

After you've got the correct API call(s) to trigger your Bamboo job, just add that as a curl step to the bottom of your rundeck job and it *should* do what you need.

FWIW - I've done this for Jenkins & Rundeck, but never in bamboo, but the solution should be the same since they're very similar products.